# Парсинг файла с менюшками C+++

Tags: c++, файлы, mingw, g++, codeblocks

Есть файл с менюшками:

0x4(количество элементов)Main Menu|0x0|Menu 1|0x0|Menu 2|0x0|Menu 3|0x0|Menu 4|0x1(конец менюшки)|0x6(количество элементов)Next Menu|0x0|Menu 1|0x0|Menu 2|0x0|Menu 3|0x0|Menu 4|0x0|Menu 5|0x0|Menu 6|0x1(конец менюшки)

| - разделитель hex кодов для легкочитаемости, его нет в файле

необходимо преобразовать его в трёхмерный динамический массив:

`char*** menus = new char**[MAX_MENUS];`

Формата `{{{4}, "Main menu", "Menu 1", "Menu 2", "Menu 3", "Menu 4"}, {{6}, "Next menu", "Menu 1", "Menu 2", "Menu 3", "Menu 4", "Menu 5", "Menu 6"}}`

использую функцию `file.get(char);`

Количество памяти неограничено, использую компилятор MinGW в Code::Blocks

К слову сама менюшка уже реализована и не требует помощи.

Comment: [трехзвездочный программист](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: У вас половина проблем исчезнет если вы перестанете использовать сырой `new`. Есть же замечательный удобный `std::vector`. Про `new` нужно знать для общего развития, но использовать его вы будете очень редко.